# tkinter >> how to get button references?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am currently trying to create a battleship game with Python and tkinter.
I need to declare 100 buttons (one for each spot that a player can fire on), and I figured out that I could do this to get them in a 10x10 grid while also storing a reference to them with the variable buttons_dict

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
board_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=5)
board_frame.grid(column=0,row=0)

COORDS_LIST = []
buttons_dict = {}

for r in range(1,11):
    for c in range(1,11):
        coord = str(r)+"_"+str(c)
        COORDS_LIST.append(coord)
        buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]] = ttk.Button(board_frame, text="O", width="2")
        buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]].grid(row=r,column=c)

root.mainloop()
```

This code creates 100 buttons displayed exactly as I need. The problem begins when I want to give a command to each one of them. What I would want is a general function (we can call it 'fire_here' for this question) that is called every time one of the buttons is pressed, but I need it to be passed either 1 or 2 arguments:
It can be the value that was appended to the COORDS_LIST when that button was created, or it can be the 'column' and 'row' values of the button.
So how do I do that OR how do I get the row/column of one button once it was placed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
board_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=5)
board_frame.grid(column=0,row=0)

COORDS_LIST = []
buttons_dict = {}

###########################################
def fire_here(x, y):
    print("column:{}, row:{}".format(x, y))
###########################################

for r in range(1,11):
    for c in range(1,11):
        coord = str(r)+"_"+str(c)
        COORDS_LIST.append(coord)
        buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]] = ttk.Button(board_frame, text="O", width="2")
        ###########################################################################
        buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]]["command"] = lambda x=c, y=r: fire_here(x, y)
        ###########################################################################
        buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]].grid(row=r,column=c)

root.mainloop()
```

All of the stuff I added is in comment boxes.  However, the important part is this:

```
buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]]["command"] = lambda x=c, y=r: fire_here(x, y)
```

Basically, it does two things:

1. Using [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), it creates a function for the current button's `command` option.  This function will be called when the button is clicked.
2. It takes the current column and row (the button's coordinates on the grid) and sets them as the default values for the `x` and `y` parameters of the function.  Moreover, when the function is called, those values will be sent to `fire_here` for processing.

---

Also, you *could* put that on the line above like so:

```
buttons_dict[COORDS_LIST[-1]] = ttk.Button(board_frame, text="O", width="2", command=lambda x=c, y=r: fire_here(x, y))
```

However, I put it on its own line to improve the code's clarity.

Comment: so when you have the lambda x=c, y=r it stores those x and y values forever?

Comment: @RSerrao - Yes, for that function.  What I showed you above is considered to be more "advanced" Python coding.  It shouldn't be though because the concept is simple.  `x=c` sets `c` as the default value for the `x` parameter of the `lambda`.  The same concept applies to `y=r`.  When the function is called, those default values are sent to `fire_here`.

Comment: Thank you then! Way simpler than another solution I found with events and event.widget stuff...