# Tkinter - Invidiualising buttons from for loop

Tags: python, button, tkinter, minesweeper

I'm currently trying to create a minesweeper game within python, but I have troubles with trying to individualize the buttons that I am creating within a for loop. The below referenced code is what I've created so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x600")
master.title("Minesweeper V 1.0")

game = Frame(master)
game.pack(pady = 10)

for i in numbers:
    for n in numbers:
        A1 = Button(game, text="", width=3, height= 1, command=randint)
        A1.grid(row=i, column=(n+1))
```

Essentially my question is how could I create a way of referencing each button as its own, rather than them all having the same name? This is so I can randomize whether the buttons set off a mine, or don't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193285/tkinter-how-to-get-button-references something like this maybe?

Comment: save them in a list or dictionary.